# Predicting the peak "amplitude" of a damped sine wave in the frequency spectrum with FFT

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In one line: Given an exponentially decaying sine wave $x(t)$, how can we predict the amplitude of the resulting peak in frequency spectrum using discrete Fourier transform.

In nuclear magnetic resonance experiments, the raw data is an exponentially decaying sinuoid(s) as a function of time (t $\geq$ 0). In order to see the frequency spectrum the standard protocol is to do a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) and display one-sided frequency spectrum [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utuaP.png).

a) Simple scenario: We have a non-decaying sine wave of frequency $\omega_0$ and amplitude $A$. FFT of this signal is two peaks (one corresponding to positive frequency and the other one at negative frequency situated at $\omega_0$ and amplitude $A/2$. Note that we have to normalize the FFT with the number of sampled points in order to get the right amplitudes in the frequency spectrum.

b) Real experimental scernaio: Let us say we have an exponentially decaying sine wave $x(t)$, then,

$$x(t) = A \sin(\omega_0 t) e^{-\alpha t} \, u(t)$$

where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside unit step function, $\alpha$ is positive and real. Now the key question is that in (a), we were able to predict the amplitude of the peaks in the frequency spectrum. It was $A/2$. In this exponentially decaying case, is there a way to predict the amplitude of the resulting peak in frequency spectrum?

An annotated figure will clarify the question. Starting from (a) a sine wave with 25 Hz and amplitude of 5 will show up as a single peak in FFT spectrum of amplitude 5/2 (two sided version) or 5 in the one-sided spectrum.

Now the same sinusoid is multiplied by an exponential with $\alpha$= 0.5. We get a much less peak height in the frequency spectrum.
In short, is there a way to predict this peak height if we know the decay constant and initial amplitude of the sine wave in FFT. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I find it hard to make out what exactly you're asking here. What is given, what are you trying to determine? Are you saying that you have $X(\omega )$ at a discrete set of points (from a FFT), and you're trying to determine $A$?

Comment: I think the key question is that if we have an exponentially decaying sine wave with amplitude A, how can I predict the peak heights (=magnitude frequency spectrum) in the FFT. For a non-decaying sine wave with amplitude A, in the frequency spectrum, the peak height is also A/2.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to find. What is a "peak height" or a "magnitude frequency spectrum"? Can you point out which property of your original expression $x(t)$ you're interested in? And again, what are the given data that you want to derive said property from?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt, I have now added the figure and hopefully the query is clear. You can see that we have peaks now in the frequency spectrum and they have a corresponding height. In the simple sine case, their height was A/2 but how can we predict the exponentially decaying sine wave case.

Comment: Oh, so you're simply interested in calculating the Fourier transform of your $x(t)$? Well - you had an expression for $X(\omega )$ in earlier versions of your question ... but that is not what you want? Are you saying that your graphs E) or F) don't agree with that $X(\omega )$? Might that be because your FFT literally calculates the Fourier transform of your graph D) over the shown finite interval of $5s$, pretending that that graph periodically repeats outside that interval? That would of course be different from the Fourier transform over the whole real (half-)axis ...

Comment: The FFT spectrum is all correct. There is no issue in calculations there. My interest is in knowing how can I predict the peak heights of the $x(t)$ after FFT. I cannot find a relation that can allow us to predict the peak height in the frequency spectrum. In this simple sine case it was $A/2$. In the exponential case $\alpha$ is involved.

Comment: We seem to be going in circles here. What is a "peak height of the $x(t)$ after FFT"? Do you want $A$ given $X(\omega )$? Or do you want the maxima of $X(\omega )$ given $x(t)$? Can you please specify what you want in terms of objects in your formulae/figures instead of wording which I, frankly, find unintelligible?

Comment: Let us look at the figures, D (raw signal) and E (two sided frequency spectrum obtained via FFT of the raw signal). The y axis of E is the magnitude of the FFT. Looking at E, we have two peaks. I want to "predict" their maximum y-value, provided I know all the values in $x(t)$, i.e., I know $A$, and $\alpha$ and $\omega_0$. In spectroscopic terms, the maximum y-value would be termed as peak height.

Comment: Ok, now in early versions of your post you had $X(\omega)$. So, isn't the maximal value of the magnitude of  $X(\omega)$ exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, but the figures are made from FFT for sampled data and finite duration, this is why I removed the $X(\omega)$

Comment: I simulated in MATLAB using the built-in `fft` command for the Fourier transform where the exponentially dampened signal is defined as `A*exp(-alpha* t) .*sin(2 * pi * frequency * t)`. Regardless of the size of the `alpha` value, there is no shift in the frequency domain at all.

Comment: Downvoting without stating any legitimate reason serves no purpose at all nor affects anything.

Comment: You are looking for Laplace transform  of $Sin(\omega t)$ at $s= \alpha+i\omega$. Simply consult the Laplace transform table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just Fourier transform your signal
$$\hat{x}(\omega)=A\int_{0}^\infty \sin(\omega_0 t)e^{-\alpha t}\,e^{i\omega t}\,dt=\frac{A\omega_0}{\alpha^2-2 i \alpha \omega+\omega_0^2-\omega^2}.$$
The peak in $|\hat{x}(\omega)|^2$ for $\alpha<\omega_0$ is at $\omega=\pm\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\alpha^2}$ of height $A(8\pi \alpha^2)^{-1}$.

The limit $\alpha\rightarrow 0$ gives you delta function peaks, which will be regulated by the time discretisation step $\delta t$. For $\alpha\delta t>1$ the peak height will then decay as $1/\alpha$.

---

There has been a (now partially deleted) discussion whether the damping shifts the peak frequency. It does. To see this, I plot $$8\pi\alpha^2|\hat{x}(\omega)|^2=8\pi A^2\frac{(\alpha\omega_0)^2}{\left(\alpha^2+\omega_0^2\right)^2+2 \omega^2 (\alpha^2-\omega_0^2)+\omega^4}$$ as a function of $\omega$ for $\omega_0=1$, $A=1$, and $\alpha=0.1$ (gold) and $\alpha=0.5$ (blue).

[image]

The separation between the peaks is reduced by an amount $\alpha^2/\omega_0$ for $\alpha\ll\omega_0$.